# Opensips - Bad From Header when I was using failover in my script

Tags: sip, sip-server, opensips

my REQUEST_ROUTE:

```
...
route [FROM_GATEWAY] {
    if ($fU=~"^999" && !$avp(new_caller)) {
        for ($var(v) in $(json(foo)[*]))
            $avp(new_caller) = $var(v);
    }

    if (!$avp(new_caller)) {
        $avp(new_caller) = $fU;
    }

    if (!do_routing($avp(new_caller),,,$avp(dst_rule_attrs),$avp(dst_gw_attrs), ,$avp(partition))) {...}

    $var(new_caller_domain) = ...;
    $var(uri) := "sip:" + $avp(new_caller) + "@" + $var(new_caller_domain);
    uac_replace_from("", "$var(uri)");


    $var(new_callee) = ...;
    $var(uri) := "sip:" + $var(new_callee) + "@" + $(ru{uri.domain});
    uac_replace_to("", "$var(uri)");

    route(RELAY);
}
```

my FAILURE_ROUTE:

```
...
failure_route [MANAGE_FAILURE] {
    if (t_check_status("403")) {
        $avp(new_caller) = NULL;
        if ($avp(new_caller)) {
            $var(isFailOver) = 1;
            route(FROM_GATEWAY);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Invite to host1 is normal, but when inviting to host 2, there is a syntax error in the 'from' and 'to' fields:

[image: log when make invite]

`From:  <sip:1111111111@42.96.x.x><sip:2222222222@42.96.x.x>;tag=XDDpmaS4Fr8vK`

`To: <sip:3333333333@125.212.y.y><sip:3333333333@103.63.z.z>`

Can someone explain what happened during when retry invite to another host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed!  Although your sequence leads to OpenSIPS producing a *malformed* SIP header, given the current implementation of lazy SIP header mangling, this is expected.  Long story short:  you should *never* call `uac_replace_from()` and `uac_replace_to()` more than one time during the processing of a single SIP message (i.e. before it gets relayed).

But why does this happen during failure route?  Well, it's because the SIP message gets *saved together* with *all un-applied mangling instructions*, such that when you re-try the routing inside failure route, you are in a very similar state to the one before `route(RELAY)`!  You then re-run the processing route, together with a 2nd set of `uac_replace_from()` and produce a malformed SIP packet.

Can I mitigate this?  Yes, you can!  In order to **avoid saving the mangling** instructions, try to *perform them inside a branch route* instead!  By doing so, the original message to be re-routed gets saved **cleanly**, without any lazy (un-applied) SIP header changes.  Some code snippets:

```
route
{

    ...
    t_on_branch("NORMALIZE_HEADERS");
    route(RELAY);
}

branch_route [NORMALIZE_HEADERS]
{
    $var(new_caller_domain) = ...;
    $var(uri) := "sip:" + $avp(new_caller) + "@" + $var(new_caller_domain);
    uac_replace_from("", "$var(uri)");

    $var(new_callee) = ...;
    $var(uri) := "sip:" + $var(new_callee) + "@" + $(ru{uri.domain});
    uac_replace_to("", "$var(uri)");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I modified header in the branch_route and it's working now!